# Fixed width text areas and full alpha madness

Tags: discussion, bug, chat

I was just working on my project while chat messaging, and I wasn't able to see what I typed!

[image: Text typed is hidden]

The hidden text is 'ur text if you typed a lot'.  You can see the rest here (posted):[image: Show text I was trying to type]

This can be pretty easily solved by allowing the user to make the textarea smaller than **540px.**  However, I would *really* like to see what I've been typing on the right, so I don't have to edit it if I make a typo.  This isn't the most issue-iest issue, but I think it can be fixed.

Also, another issue, is the **full alpha madness!**  As you can see, is that the text from me that starts with '@hichris123 OAuth stuff' is hidden a bit by my profile picture (and could be hidden by tags).  Hooray for issues! :P

Comment: It would be nice if they auto-hide the right pane when the browser is resized to smaller sizes.. something like facebook does..

Comment: Auto hide the dock maybe? Or even better, don't use a mac :P

Comment: @ɥʇǝS don't tell him to use Ubuntu, then he will need to sudu this and bash this... at the end he will end up with his own Linux version.. which will only serve one purpose, SE chat!

Comment: @ɥʇǝS We're friends, aren't me?  After all, we're both Unix based!

Comment: @MIH You obviously don't know Ubuntu that well :P

Comment: @ManofSnow I'm not sure that makes us friends.. (hardware wise). I personally hate Apple ;P

Comment: @ɥʇǝS ooh, I remember now, Ubunto is the "Windowszized" version of Linux ;)

Comment: (I meant *me to my ubove post)

Comment: @ɥʇǝS Ubuntu for Android, Ubuntu for Mac, Ubuntu for Windows - when does it end?  (I know it's a Linux OS, that's all I know :P I emulated it on my Mac a couple of times so I could run two things at once on my computer with a different "Mac Address")

Comment: This is even worse on mobile chrome, which forces a zoom in (same effect as seen in the screenshots) on textarea focus.